# Wraparound writing system?

Tags: writing-systems

I don't know if linguistics is the right place to ask about writing systems (and if not please let me know where to look) but here's the question.  When reading something, I often find that when I finish a line and go to the next that I end up picking the wrong line to start reading which slows me down/breaks my concentration.  I was wondering if there's a language that doesn't read from left to right or right to left, but reads both ways; switching orientation each line so you can read in one continuous block without having to jump around the page.

Comment: I don't know of any modern language that uses this system, but it is attested in  more than one ancient language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Boustrophedon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon) is a kind of bi-directional text, mostly seen in ancient manuscripts and other inscriptions. Every other line of writing is flipped or reversed, with reversed letters. Rather than going left-to-right as in modern English, or right-to-left as in Arabic and Hebrew, alternate lines in boustrophedon must be read in opposite directions. Also, the individual characters are reversed, or mirrored.

[image: Boustrophedon]
<sup>(image courtesy of Wikipedia)</sup>

[Egyptian hieroglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_hieroglyphs) are also known to be read in LTR or RTL directions, but I think, no document contained both directions at the same time.

---

All modern writing systems have *some* order in which the symbols are aligned. However, there are systems where each symbol carries a "bigger" or "smaller" unit of information. Compare letter-based Latin script to ideographic writing systems like Chinese and Japanese.

Hence, albeit you can't completely eliminate losing track of symbols, the probability that you **trackback within the same row** can be higher or lower.

Your question also seems to be related to **Rapid Reading** techniques (RR). If you take classes of RR, you will be taught to overcome several factors that commonly reduce your reading performance. Here are some of these:

- Replacing a sequential word-by-word reading to **seeing a whole page at once** (or, actually, square blocks of text).
- **Avoiding linear reading**. Alphabetic writing systems imply the words aligned horizontally. Your eyes follow a word and it requires training to follow several lines at once.

Further details: [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2005/752) at Chinese.SE.

---

Ideographic writing systems can also be written right-to-left and left-to-right. Here's a nice proof:

Su Hui, a first century Chinese poet, wrote a poem in the form of a 29 by 29 character grid. Her poem can be read forwards, backwards, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, allowing for 2,848 different readings.

[image: poem]